# Delay/offset crontab */x scheduling by a certain amount of time

Tags: cron, scheduling

I'm running a script every 4 days with

```
0 */96 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

However I want to offset this such that I can run a second script every 4 days, but spaced apart from the first script by 2 days. Thus the end result would be

```
Script 1
wait 2 days
Script 2
wait 2 days
Script 1
wait 2 days
Script 2
```

Is there syntax for this sort of scheduling? I would imagine it would be like

```
0 48+*/96 * * * /path/to/script2.sh
```

Comment: What distro? My man 5 crontab says the range for hour is 0-23, so the step only includes hour 0, and the job runs every day at midnight. Have you verified your job only runs every fourth day? Specifically, how can it know which is the "first" day?

Comment: I found this schedule on another thread, but it appears it is incorrect, so I am now using `0 0 */3 * * /path/to/script.sh` instead. I'm on ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to span between the day selectors and the time selectors in crontab. Nor any way to deal with the month/week/day model cleanly.

The simplest way is to over-schedule the tasks, and have them check whether "today is the day". If you can't change the tasks, wrapper them in appropriate scripts. Dealing with date checks in the crontab command line is a last resort.

Your check in bash would get seconds since the epoch, convert to days, and make a modulus check. You would need to calibrate your 4-day sequence manually (0,1,2,3) as a one-time, depending on your two base dates for the series.

```
Paul--) cat day4
#! /bin/bash

Day=$(( $( date '+%s' ) / 86400 ))

(( Day % 4 == 0 )) || exit 0

printf 1>&2 'Starting task for day %d (%d)\n' "${Day}" "$(( Day % 4 ))"

Paul--) ./day4
Starting task for day 18416 (0)
Paul--)
```